# npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden npm publish

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to publish public package on npm but I have this error

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@clem_b%2fweather - Forbidden
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

So in first watch my `package.json`below.

```json
{
  "name": "@clem_b/weather",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "description": "weather cli",
  "main": "build/main.js",
  "types": "build/main.d.ts",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ClementBolin/weatherCLI#readme",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ClementBolin/weatherCLI.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc",
    "start": "npm run build && node build/mai.js"
  },
  "bin": {
    "app": "bin/weatherCLI"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "weather",
    "today",
    "rain",
    "sun"
  ],
  "author": "clem_b",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
    "@types/oauth": "^0.9.1",
    "@types/ora": "^3.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "prepublish": "npm run build",
  "dependencies": {
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "oauth": "^0.9.15",
    "ora": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

So after end to write my code, I decide to publish my code on npm, so I create npm account, I use `npm login`for connect to my account. After this I run the following command `npm publish --access public`and I have error write in top.
I search on many topics, but I don't find solution

Answer (score 23, accepted):

just ran into this myself.  I created a new NPM account and then immediately authenticated via `npm login`.

Then, I ran `npm publish --access public` and received the exact same error message.

I was able to resolve the issue by verifying my email account for NPM (doh).

Comment: Email verification was the case for me too.

Comment: Same here ... a little hint in the docs would be great

Answer (score 4):

Probably there is already a package with the same name present on npm. Change package name in package.json and try again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was resolved after I created a team (within my NPM organization) and added myself as a member to that team.

see: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1012#issuecomment-629546298

Answer (score 0):

In npm profile, in ACCOUNT section, you must activate 2FA and after select "Enabled for authorization and publishing" inside of 2FA options.

If already do this, verify if your project has the same name of another project registered. In this case if has, just change the name.

Answer (score 0):

**check if the name is reserved in npm
in my case the name was alrady used
also try**

```sh
sudo npm install -g https://tls-test.npmjs.com/tls-test-1.0.0.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

So my scenario was i was using jenkins to publish the npm was using npm publish it was giving error that i cannot push after 1.0.0 so after checking i found that the in package.json file in version it was mentioned "1.0.0" so i needed to change the build number as per my jenkins build i used sed to do that

Answer (score 0):

I updated the name part in package.json and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be happens when you are using LAN(private network) network and if in that network IP is applied for restricting.

In my case this was the case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**1. Authentication Issues: ** -- Check npm login status:** Run `npm whoami` to verify you're logged in with the correct account that has publishing permissions.
**Log in if needed: ** If not logged in, run `npm login` and enter your npm credentials.

**2. Existing Package Name:**

- **Check for existing package:** Use `npm view pack-ui` to see if the package name is already taken.
- **Choose a different name:** If it exists, rename your package in `package.json` to a unique name.

**3. Organization Permissions:**

- **Verify permissions:** If publishing under an organization scope (e.g., `@your-org/pack-ui`), ensure you have publishing permissions within that organization.

**4.npm Cache** -- **Clear cache:** Try clearing the npm cache with `npm cache clean --force`.